# Can you provide the de-comprehended way to write the below code

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

```
d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}
d = { k + 'c' : v * 2 for k : v in d.items() if v > 2}
```

The output is

```
{ 'cc': 6 , 'dc': 8}
```

Answer (score 0):

This dictionary comprehension is equivalent to:

```
# Set up a new dictionary to hold the result
d_new = {}
# Iterate over key/value pairs
for k, v in d.items():
    # If the value is greater than 2
    if v > 2:
        # Append to the new dictionary as required.
        d_new[k + 'c'] = v*2
```

**Output:**

```
>>> d_new
{'cc': 6, 'dc': 8}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comprehensions are pretty straight-forward to transform to regular code (and the other way around). You can do this in-place by using the [`pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) method:

```py
d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}
for k in list(d.keys()):
    v = d.pop(k)
    if v > 2:
        d[k + 'c'] = v * 2
print(d)
```

Gives:

```
{'cc': 6, 'dc': 8}
```